# Android-sdk: no folder named "Platform-tools" in Program Files(x86)/Android/android-sdk/

Tags: android

I have installed android-sdk and configured my eclipse as per the instructions on the page http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing
However, as soon as the SDK Manager tries to update, it gets an error message regarding adb.exe in Platform-tools directory. I checked the android-sdk folder but couldd not find any such directory.

I am using Windows 7 (Home Basic), 64 bit, and am behind a proxy (netmon.iitb.ac.in)

Comment: you may want to share the exact error message u got to get help from the geeks around here :)

Answer (score 3):

Try run the Android SDK as Administrator (right click on it and choose Run as Admin) it should solve this issue. I think SDK trying to re-arrange folders as per new folder structure and it has no rights to do so inside programs folder.

else,
unninstall and install again.